# Estimating an unknown restricted Markov Chain from partial measurements

Tags: estimation, markov-process, inference

There is an Markov chain $M$ defined on states $1, ..., N$ with the special property that it only has transitions $p_i$ from $i$ to $i + 1$ , $q_{i + 1}$ from $i + 1$ to $i$, and $r_i = 1 - p_i - q_i$ from $i$ to $i$ (for $i \in [N - 1]$; $p_N = 0$ and $q_1 = 0$ since there is no successor/predecessor state). We know our chain respects this special structure, but we don't know the transition probabilities.

Our data about the process is generated as follows:

1. Start in some known state $n_0 \in [N]$
2. For $k = 0, ... , {t - 1}$:

   1. Go to state $n_k$ in $M$
   2. Take $n_k$ many steps in $M$
   3. Set $n_{k + 1}$ as the current state in $M$
3. Output $n_0,...,n_{t}$

In other words, we only have partial information about our walk through M. But from many of these $n_0,...,n_{t}$ I want to be able to infer the transition probabilities of $M$. How should I go about this? Is there a standard procedure for this? If so, is there an implementation in Matlab (or R)?

Comment: So this is a (finite-state) [birth-death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process) chain (with self-loops, which the link doesn't mention, but are common in the literature)?

Comment: @cardinal yeah, we are trying to estimate a hidden Moran process, basically.

Comment: I'm a little unsure of your description above. In step two, it sounds like you do a fixed number of (unobserved) transitions where the fixed number is the label of the state that you're in? Is that correct?

Comment: @cardinal that is exactly correct. After that many transitions, you are a new state which you observe and then repeat.

Comment: basically, in step 2.1 I am thinking of $n_k$ as a state and in 2.2 I am treating it as an integer.

Comment: Thanks. That's what it read like, but I wasn't completely sure since it seemed to be used in two different ways. :)

Comment: To start out with: note that your procedure induces a Markov chain on the observed states. So, you can start by estimating those transition probabilities. Each of these can be written as sums of products of probabilities of the underlying chain. From each state $k$ you can end up in any state from 1 to $\max(2k, N)$ so if $N=2n$ for some $n$, that should give $n(n+1)/2 +n/2 = n^2/2 + N = N^2/8 + N$ equations. There are only $2N-2$ free parameters. So, the estimation is at least feasible, even if it gets messy analytically.

Comment: @cardinal yeah, it is definitely possible, but I was hoping there would be a clean way with nice ways to do confidence or error estimates...

Answer (score 1):

If you call $A$ the transition matrix of your [birth-death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth%E2%80%93death_process) chain, with its special structure of only three non-zero terms per row, the probability to observe $n_0,\ldots,n_t$ is
$$
[A^{n_0}]_{n_0n_1}\,[A^{n_1}]_{n_1n_2}\cdots[A^{n_{t-1}}]_{n_{t-1}n_t}\,.
$$
You therefore are able to compute exactly the likelihood associated with your chain. From there, any standard method depending on the likelihood (Bayesian, MLE, &tc.) applies.